# Razor Syntax when performing a Double.Parse in cshtml file

Tags: asp.net, razor, syntax

I am trying perform a Double.Parse in an ASP.NET cshtml file using Razor syntax. I want to check and see if epc.EditAmount is equal to zero and conditionally add a style. It's passed in as a string so I wanted to turn it into a double and compare. For some reason, the syntax is bad here and I can't figure out quite why.

```
<dd class="@(Double.Parse(epc.EditAmount) != 0.0 ? "RedFont" : "") ">
    @epc.EditAmount.Replace("$", "")
</dd>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might want to do it this way

```
@{
    var classValue = Double.Parse(epc.EditAmount) != 0.0 
        ? "RedFont"
        : "";
}

<dd class="@Html.Raw(classValue)">
    @epc.EditAmount.Replace("$", "")
</dd>
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. I can't figure out for the life of me why the other was wrong.

Comment: Glad to help. Cheers!